# xpath specific selection with condition

Tags: xpath, conditional-statements

this might be simple, but I would like to select everything within `<div class="rc-box-citations-body">` under the condition that it must belong to `<div class="definitionBox" id="meaning-1-1">`, thereby uniquely identifying it. How can I do that with xpath? Thanks.

```
 <div class="definitionIndent">
  <div class="definitionNumber">1.a</div>
  <div class="definitionIndent">
    <div class="definitionBox" id="meaning-1-1">
      <span class="textmedium">
        <span class="stampNoBorder">text</span>
        <span class="definition">text</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="definitionBox">
      <div class="rc-box-citations">
        <div class="rc-box-citations-top">
          <span class="rc-citations-north-west">&#160;</span>
          <span class="rc-citations-north-east">&#160;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="rc-box-citations-body"><span class="citat">text</span> <a class="sourcepop" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="source">text</span><span class="popup">text</span></a></div>
        <div class="rc-box-citations-bot">
          <span class="rc-citations-south-west">&#160;</span>
          <span class="rc-citations-south-east">&#160;</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "under the condition that it must belong to" ...meaning `<div class="rc-box-citations-body">` is a descendant of `<...id="meaning-1-1">`?

Comment: yes, please clarify the situation. In your XML I see no matches meeting the criteria you've provided. There are no divs with `class='rc-box-citations-body'` as descendants of the div with `id='meaning-1-1'`.

Answer (score 0):

If I modify your xml slightly, and take *under the condition that it must belong to* to mean *that is a descendant of*.... then this xpath works

`//div[@class='definitionBox'][@id='meaning-1-2']//div[@class='rc-box-citations-body']`

The XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<div class="definitionIndent">
  <div class="definitionNumber">1.a</div>
  <div class="definitionIndent">
    <div class="definitionBox" id="meaning-1-1">
      <span class="textmedium">
        <span class="stampNoBorder">text</span>
        <span class="definition">text</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="definitionBox" id="meaning-1-2">
      <div class="rc-box-citations">
        <div class="rc-box-citations-top">
          <span class="rc-citations-north-west"></span>
          <span class="rc-citations-north-east"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="rc-box-citations-body">
          <span class="citation">text</span>
          <a class="sourcepop" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <span class="source">text</span>
            <span class="popup">text</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="rc-box-citations-bot">
          <span class="rc-citations-south-west"></span>
          <span class="rc-citations-south-east"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The tool I used is XPathVisualizer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the `//div[@class='rc-box-citations-body']` doesn't match anything, but that's because I made a mistake in my example above (I'm a newbie, got some trouble finding the right terms to say what exactly I need). I've edited it now, does that shed some more light on what to do?